# Mixing Custom/Drop Down attributes in VirtueMart for Joomla

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am trying to add a product that requires form fields...however, by creating the attributes that dropdown, then custom attributes, it displays that way, Drop down first, Custom Second.  Is there a way to create a mix of custom, then drop down, then custom?  See current site:

www.MSLawMart.com 
Select Legal Forms -> No Fault Divorce...you'll see what I'm saying.

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file that handles handles the rendering of the product details page & form is:

```
administrator\components\com_virtuemart\html\shop.product_details.php
```

it does so like this:

```
  $addtocart = "<div>
    <form action=\"". $mm_action_url."index.php\" method=\"post\" name=\"addtocart\" id=\"addtocart\">"
          .$ps_product_attribute->list_attribute($product_id)
          // added for the advanced attribute modification
          .$ps_product_attribute->list_advanced_attribute($product_id)
          // end added for advanced attribute modification
          .$ps_product_attribute->list_custom_attribute($product_id);
          // end added for custom attribute modification
```

so you would need to do some customisation/tweaking in the those list_*_attribute() functions to make them render the tables/rows differently.  you'll find them in

```
\administrator\components\com_virtuemart\classes\ps_product_attribute.php
```